# Which one is better approach while performing multiple background tasks Kotlin Coroutines or ThreadPool?

Tags: android, performance, threadpoolexecutor, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to implement start syncing process while app comes foreground.

I want to make multiple API call in the background thread, Which one will be better approach for this scenario Kotlin Coroutines or ThreadPool executor

I have tried with Kotlin Coroutines, but it seems like it try to execute all functions call in parallel which cause some Lag in APP initial times. is there a best approach to execute multiple functions in parallel

Answer (score 0):

of course, Kotlin Coroutines, because coroutines aren't necessarily bound to any particular thread. A coroutine can start executing in one thread, suspend execution, and resume on a different thread. Coroutines aren't managed by the operating system. They're managed at the user space level by the Kotlin Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Co-routines are the way to go.

**Why? :**

1. They are cheap.
2. Increases code readability.
3. Configuration setup is less (as compared to RxJava) for simple tasks.

Comment: why are you comparing to Rx when the question is about threadpool executors

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 viewModelScope.launch{
            val function1Async=async{ function1()}
            val function2Async=async{function2()
            function1Async.await() 
            function2Async.await()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the alternative is to use ThreadPools, then you should use coroutines. They are built to make this easier. Also, you would save some memory since you would be sharing threads with other processes.

If what you need is a single thread that's continuously running in the background. Then maybe a thread is the way to go to ensure it's execution is not interrupted by a pending coroutine. Although an isolated single threaded dispatcher should solve this problem (if you have it).

You mentioned experiencing lag? Was this lag averted when you used a threadpool? If this is an issue, then fire the coroutines from another coroutine. :)